# Flask sqlalchemy using same model with different databases

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I found [this](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/binds/) article which describes how to use multiple databases in flask and sqlalchemy, but the problem with this is that each model is associated with a different binding.

Is it possible to use the same model on different databases?

Comment: Show what you've tried

Comment: Probably you are looking for [Horizontal Sharding](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/horizontal_shard.html). Also look in the [example](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/examples.html#examples-sharding) related to the topic.

Comment: [Using multiple databases with single sqlalchemy model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35789921/using-multiple-databases-with-single-sqlalchemy-model), might interest you. It does not use `Flask-SQLAlchemy` but you can easily apply it to that.