# How to switch Flask-SQLAlchemy's SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI b/w two databases?

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

My Flask application has all the configuration in a *Config* class with the *SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI* value, and Flask-SQLAlchemy loads this value into its configuration.

I have two different SQLite databases with exactly the same table schemas, but different data. The Flask application will be using data from one of those two databases initially.

Now, by making an API call I want to switch to the other database, such that now onwards Flask will be interacting with this other database. So, this API endpoint is basically a database toggle switch. What's a reasonable solution to achieve this?

The solution I am thinking of is to change the value of *SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI* in the *Config* class as a result of that API call and re-initialize the Flask-SQLAlchemy object by reloading the configuration into the app object and eventually SQLAlchemy.

**Edit:**

Will it be better and possible to rather use a single database with two tables (same schema, different name) and switch between tables instead of databases?

Comment: Should different clients be able to access either of the two databases at the same time?

Comment: Look at [`binds`](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/binds/). It's hard to imagine how tearing down and rebuilding the SQLAlchemy object will work in a webserver context. What if there are clients connected, mid query?

Comment: @SuperShoot Answering to the different client scenario, to be honest, I didn't think it through. But, yes if that would be the desired case if can access either database simultaneously.

Comment: Binds can let me use different models/tables from different databases, but I was looking to use the same table from two different databases. Please check the Edited question.

Comment: Yes I'm with you now. [You can use the same models across different databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35789921/using-multiple-databases-with-single-sqlalchemy-model). Instead of using flask-sqlalchemy you'll need to use sqlalchemy directly and setup your app using the [pattern documented here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/sqlalchemy/#declarative). The most important thing is to ensure that you call `remove()` on every session that you create in your teardown.

Comment: This is a good read too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38374005/flask-sqlalchemy-how-do-sessions-work-with-multiple-databases#38375161

Comment: ...although not specific to using the same models across dbs. From what I can tell, the bind key in flask-sqlalchemy is associated to the db table itself which is why I think it’s probably neater to use SQLA directly and the method outlined in that answer above.